# Nokogiri XML parsing failure when &#x09; or &#x0D; present in text

Tags: ruby, xml, jruby, nokogiri

Nokogiri seems unable to handle the subject escape sequences for tab and carriage return when they appear in text (i.e. between XML nodes). When I disable the RECOVER parse option, the error that is thrown is as follows:

```
Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Content is not allowed in prolog.
nokogiri/XmlDocument.java:344:in `read_memory'
/Users/pivotal/.gem/jruby/1.9.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1-java/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:55:in `parse'
/Users/pivotal/.gem/jruby/1.9.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1-java/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb:33:in `XML'
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this problem without filtering out the escape sequences prior to handing off to Nokogiri?

UPDATE

A local example of one of these instances is:

```
<KeyIssues> &#x09;</KeyIssues>
```

and to be clear, removing the sequence eliminates the problem. Also, although I'm not sure it's relevant, the file is encoded UTF-16 Little Endian and I'm passing the appropriate encoding information to Nokogiri.  Finally, I'm using:

```
jruby 1.7.11 (1.9.3p392) 2014-02-24 86339bb on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_55-b13 [darwin-x86_64]
```

and Nokogiri 1.6.2.1

Comment: I just tried `Nokogiri::XML.parse( '<text>Hello&#09;</text>' )` in MRI Ruby 2.1.1, Nokogiri version 1.6.2.rc2, and it parsed OK. Without checking other combinations, not sure whether it is JRuby-specific or Nokogiri version, or xml lib version . .

Comment: could you show the XML snippet?

Comment: This error isn’t due to the tab and cr entities, but rather invalid XML. It looks like you have (non whitespace) content _outside_ the XML root. You can have a literal tab or cr here, but not entities.

Comment: @matt I don't think so. There are no characters outside of the XML root aside from the 16-bit BOM which indicates UTF-16 LE encoding. A Google search indicates this error arises due to character encoding issues and further, elimination of this escape sequence eliminates the error.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin yeah, since your update I can reproduce the error (nearly - I get the similar “The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.”). However I get the same error even _without_ the entity. I _don‘t_ get an error if I add a BOM or XML declaration to the file, or if I make sure the encoding is right in Ruby before passing to Nokogiri. I wonder if when you strip out the entities you are also fixing the encoding, which is the actual issue? Can you provide the actual code you are using to read and parse the file?